# Import flask not working on my macbook pro m1 chip

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

import flask shows an error in my Vs code.
when I tried to check the version I found 2 versions of python installed.
I don't know if due to that it is causing the problem.
what should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppHRX.png)

Comment: are you sure you have Flask installed in your Python 2.7 version on your machine?

Comment: Some answers are pointing out that your problem is that flask is not installed, but it is clear that you tried to install flask but it returned another error, that you don't have typing module. Follow the error messages cause they look like to be pointing you to what to do. I will recommend that you use virtualenv if you don't want to have unwanted modules system wide.

Comment: don't use Python 2.7 (deprecated, the OS uses it), switch over to the other installed Python interpreter (should be 3.x), and use the `venv` module for virtual environment, read the Python docs of VSC

Answer (score 1):

The environment you are using hasn't installed the package you want to import caused the first problem. The pip of python 2.7 installs the flask failed, cause the second problem.

You should select the right environment. You can follow these steps:

1. Under your project runs: `python3 -m venv .venv` to create a new virtual environment.
2. Select the environment you have just created: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> ==> `Python: Select Interpreter` to choose the environment.
3. Take <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> ==> `Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>), opens a command prompt for your selected interpreter. You should find (.venv) in the terminal, this means you had selected the right environment.
4. Check which pip you are using: in the terminal, types: `pip --version`, it will determine which environment your package will be installed to.
5. Install the package you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is all because you haven't installed the module. It wouldn't really run without installing.

So you would have to install it. The issue here is that I don't use MAC so I can't explain but I have found a video that would explain it to you.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBdZZGPpYxg

Watch the video. In the video they explain how to install `requests` module. You can simply write `flask` instead to `requests` while they tell you how to install.

Hope this helps. If still this doesn't make sense, please ask me in the comments. :)

Thank You! :D

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run Flask in your mac M1 Chip is

1. Install Anaconda
   --> https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda-navigator
2. Go to The Terminal
3. Enter "conda activate" in the terminal without "" obviously :)
4. Create a file "app.py"
5. paste this code in "app.py" below

```
from flask import Flask
 

app = Flask(__name__)
 

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World'
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

6. Now open your code editor eg. VS Code or Brackets or anything.
7. Now Inside the Terminal Go to the directory of your "app.py" file
8. In that directory enter "python3 app.py"

and there you go :)